# I cannot create any event handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I recently started to create a new project, after completing the UI it was time for me to start the back-end. When double clicking on buttons, labels, picture boxes or basically any tool nothing happens. It does not create a new event. In properties there is no option to create a click event. I do not have any warnings or errors since I have not changed any code. The project is a ASP.Net web application with standard web forms.

I am using visual studio 19

```
protected void RegisterBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        
{
            
LogoImg.Visible = false;
       
 }
```

Comment: You can _edit_ your question.

Comment: it is strange, you should have event properties on the right corner if you click on the UI button. also create the event function

Comment: @langme creating the event by code also does not work, after debug when clicking on the button it just gets selected but does not execute any code

Comment: Please try a youtube tuto , the event is so easy with a new project

Comment: You are showing a click handler. But is the Event registered?

Comment: Did check on youtube, do all of the videos I watched had an option under events called click which I do not have

Comment: @Fildor Please explain how I can register the event

Comment: Can you post a Screenshot of your IDE with the Button in focus and the properties pane on "events" tab?

Comment: There should be somewhere a line like `myButton.Click += RegisterBtn_Click;` (where "myButton" is the actual name of your button reference)

Comment: I assume you closed the project. exit VS, re-launch and then re-load?

Comment: please add aspx code of the button to the question